# What would the Newtonian-esque approximation for gravity be in other numbers of dimensions, according to relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime-dimensions

In 3 dimensions, gravity can usually be approximated using Newton's equation for gravity, $g=G\frac{m}{r^2}$. There have been [answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48447/gravity-force-strength-in-1d-2d-3d-and-higher-spatial-dimensions) here saying the acceleration of gravity in $n$ dimensions would be, but they are based on Newton's gravity equation. What does general relativity say about it, and what would the Newtonian approximation look like?

Comment: In relativity, gravity is not a force at all. So not sure what you are looking for here.

Comment: Ah you caught a typo. Thanks.

Comment: An object following a geodesic (i.e. in free fall, only influenced by the "force" of gravity) has zero four-acceleration by definition. That is the essence of the principle of equivalence. Again, not sure what you are looking for here. The equation of a geodesic? Those are what you can get when you solve Einsteins field equations.

Comment: When I said "acceleration" of gravity, I meant the acceleration an observer on the ground would observe in an object in freefall. Does my new edit clear things up?

Comment: Am I correct that the expression you are looking for in the 3+1 dimensions case is present in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/551757/why-are-stationary-observers-accelerating-in-the-schwarzschild-metric-intuitive) Q&A? And you are wondering what the corresponding expression is for other numbers of dimensions?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Maybe? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I don't think GR can say anything about higher-D spaces, like 4+1. In 5D, the $T$ has 15 independent components, up 5 from 10 in 3+1D. I have no idea what physical sense can be ascribed to them. Do you? An additional vector field and a scalar field of unknown dynamics? Besides, solving the EFE fully in 5D even with a simplest nontrivial metric is horrendously hard. Of note is the Kaluza-Klein theory, q.v., a 5D theory but with a set of "cylindrical constraints," IIRC, of all $\partial/\partial x_5$ vanishing, describes classical GR+EM; still, it generates an extra non-physical scalar field.

Answer (score 3):

Unsurprisingly, GR recovers Newton. With $1$ time dimension and $n$ space dimensions, the Schwarzschild metric is $ds^2=-fdt^2+dr^2/f+r^2d\Omega_{n-1}^2$ with $f(\infty)=1,\,f^\prime\propto m/r^{n-1}$. The geodesic deviation equation $\ddot{x}^a=-\Gamma^a_{bc}\dot{x}^b\dot{x}^c$ includes the nonrelativistic special case$$\ddot{x}^r\approx -\Gamma^r_{tt}=\frac12g^{rr}g_{tt,\,r}=-\frac12ff^\prime\approx-\frac12f^\prime\propto-\frac{m}{r^{n-1}}.$$

Comment: I think what you're saying is that it ends up behaving like the Newtonian model in simple cases. Is this correct?

Comment: @zucculent Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (perhaps oversimplified) way of looking at this.

For any description of gravity which can be well-approximated with a 1/r^2 dependency, the presence of extra spatial dimensions can be inferred by "leakage" of gravity into the extra dimensions which manifests as a deviation from strict 1/r^2 dependence in the (3+1) dimensions we inhabit. So one test of the presence of extra spatial dimensions is to look for deviations from 1/r^2 behavior caused by leakage into the extra dimensions, and to date none have been detected.